# Document Listener works for one side only in swing event

Tags: java, swing, jtable, rowfilter, documentlistener

I have a `JTable`and two `JButton`s on a `JDialog`.When I click on one `JButton`(Active button) I could load some data to this `JTable`. Also this is same as to second `JButton`(Inactive button) .

Here are some screen shots,

[image: Active button]

[image: Inactive button]

Then I try to search data on the table using the text filed. So I use a document listener for this purpose . But this is only working for `Active button`.

These are the steps which I used to do this ,

```
Vector originalTableModel;
DocumentListener documentListener;
```

In the Constructor of the JDialog,

```
originalTableModel = (Vector) ((DefaultTableModel) searchTable.getModel()).getDataVector().clone();
//add document listener to jtextfield to search contents as soon as something typed on it
addDocumentListener();
```

Other steps and methods,

```
private void searchTextKeyReleased(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt)                                       
{                                           
    searchTableContents(searchText.getText());
}

private void addDocumentListener()
{
    documentListener = new DocumentListener()
    {
        public void changedUpdate(DocumentEvent documentEvent)
        {
            search();
        }

        public void insertUpdate(DocumentEvent documentEvent)
        {
            search();
        }

        public void removeUpdate(DocumentEvent documentEvent)
        {
            search();
        }

        private void search()
        {
            searchTableContents(searchText.getText());
        }

    };
}

public void searchTableContents(String searchString)
{
    DefaultTableModel currtableModel = (DefaultTableModel) searchTable.getModel();
    //To empty the table before search
    currtableModel.setRowCount(0);
    //To search for contents from original table content
    for (Object rows : originalTableModel)
    {
        Vector rowVector = (Vector) rows;
        for (Object column : rowVector)
        {
            if (column.toString().toLowerCase().contains(searchString.toLowerCase()))
            {
                //content found so adding to table
                currtableModel.addRow(rowVector);
                break;
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Actually I want to do this search part for both `JButtons`.

Have any ideas about this ?

Thanks .

Comment: You need to maintain separate references to the models, so one is the active dry and one is the search model, when you change views, you switch the references

Comment: Can you explain with more facts ?

Comment: The basic idea is, you have (at least) two table models, one you want to search, one which is currently active or visible (applied to the table). Basically as required, you would simply switch the references so your "searchModel" reference always pointed to the table model you want to search and your "activeModel" reference always pointed to the same model which was applied to your JTable

Comment: @MadProgrammer :- I am confused.

Comment: @MadProgrammer : - Can you give me an example about your opinion ?

Comment: I have to get my daughter bathed and into bed, so it might be a while

Comment: @MadProgrammer :- It's fine dear .

Comment: (MadProgrammer probably complicating the simple thing) everything depends of if and how is row considered to be flagges as "active / inactive" (sure, column with this flag couldn't be visible in the JTables view , present in XxxTableModel only), then with success by using only one model (you can to filtering from model to view by sets RowFilter to two or more column, 1st. Boolean - "active / inactive", 2nd, from JTextFlied )

Comment: for better help sooner post an SSCCE / MCVE, short, runnable, compilable, with hardcoded value for DefaultTableModel in local variable